# While fetching JSON data using ajax i am getting Unexpected token : error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I need to fetch data from url returned data was JSON.but while trying to fetch i am getting

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

here is the code please check it.

can you please tell me why i am getting this error and how to solve it.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var Url = "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/ajaxGetQuoteJSON.jsp?symbol=LIBERTSHOE";
    $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: Url + '&callback=?',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, text, errorThrown) {  }
 });});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

find fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/vbpradeep/kf9ad1t3/

Comment: @Div even though i am getting same error..please check it.please provide fiddle link if it works

Comment: @Div if i remove XML error will occur

Comment: "xmlHttpRequest cannot load" error occur if i remove..can you please provide fiddle link for that...

Comment: That would be the same-origin policy, the URL doesn't send CORS headers.

Comment: @Div thats my error how to resolve this..

Comment: @Div did u get data from that ajax post..please check with console its throwing error..

Comment: @PradeepKumar Can you please add that in the question as snippet

Comment: @Div https://jsfiddle.net/vbpradeep/kf9ad1t3/

Comment: @PradeepKumar, Okay, you get cross origin error, and for that you can refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310450/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-concept)

Comment: If you removed the dataType='jsonp', you will get the following error: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 501.

This means the service is using CORS and your origin is not included in the list of allowed sites to make an ajax request from another domain

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you cant build the URL string inside the JSON

instead of creating it in the JSON like this:

```
url: Url + '&callback=?',
```

you can just add it to the end of the original URL string:

```
var Url = "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/ajaxGetQuoteJSON.jsp?symbol=LIBERTSHOE&callback=?'";
```

http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/pEOgZj

This removes the syntax error although codepen still shows a cross origin error.

Comment: even though i am getting same error..please check it.please provide fiddle link if it works

Comment: @PradeepKumar this new error is not the same error that you posted about, We would need more information about the API you are using, and possibly needs to be asked in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves the issue.

```js
  

      $(document).ready(function() {
        var Url = "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/ajaxGetQuoteJSON.jsp?symbol=LIBERTSHOE&callback=?";
        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',            
            url: Url            
        }).then(function(data){
            //What should happen in success scenarios
            console.log('Success');
            alert(data)
        },function(data){
            //what should happen in failure scenarios
            console.log('Failure Block');
            alert(data)
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nope, I see its still going into failure block

Comment: did u get any ans regarding my query