# I'm having trouble fetching from my API, every time I get an HTTP2 Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, http2

I have a PHP API that sends JSON.

Whenever I try to fetch that JSON I get:

[image: ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR]
[image: Headers]
[image: Headers 2]

My .htaccess file looks like this:

[image: I'm usign 000Webhost]

I'm completely stumped on how to allow the fetch to actually fetch, any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using JavaScript to access data on another domain? If so, look into [CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25311247/231316)

Comment: I am & did as described already & still no does.

Comment: Check your browser developer console for errors. Remember that CORS has to be enabled _by the server you are accessing_. There’s nothing in JS that can make this work. The alternative is to write your own server-side proxy for your JS to access.

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problems

Your [2nd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4zSq.png) and [3rd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlwde.png) screenshots indicate that you're adding an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the request. However, [that header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) is a *response* header, not a *request* header; adding it to a request is pointless and counterproductive. Moreover, because it isn't listed in the value of your `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header. Therefore, CORS preflight fails.

Besides, [your 4th screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIqwQ.png) indicates that you're explicitly allowing the `Origin` header, but there's never a need for that, because that header is special and automatically added by the browser.

### Solution

Stop sending an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with your requests.
You can also drop `Origin` from the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header in your CORS configuration.