# in an AWS Lambda function I'm trying to use: https://www.dan.me.uk/torlist/ but getting a 403 error

Tags: python, aws-lambda, tor

Here is the code snippet:

```
def is_tor_ip(ip_address):
    # Use TorDNSEL service to check if an IP address is a Tor exit node
    tor_dnsel_url = f"https://www.dan.me.uk/torlist/"
    try:
         with request.urlopen(tor_dnsel_url) as response:
            tor_exit_nodes = response.read().decode('utf-8').split('\n')
            return ip_address in tor_exit_nodes
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error checking Tor exit node: {e}")
        return False
```

Here is the log from CloudWatch:
Error checking Tor exit node: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Here are the permissions assigned to the functions Role:
AmazonS3FullAccess

AmazonS3ObjectLambdaExecutionRolePolicy

AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess

AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole-0d3cae5e-6e55-437d-ad73-5d1546eff3fa

lambda-read-s3

I've tried adding user-agent headers to no avail. I'm not really a programmer just a security guy trying to automate a function to report on Tor IP usage.

Comment: Nice question. I suppose it's some problem related with [Same-Origin Security Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25311247/9997212), but I'm not sure. Maybe someone else can help.

Comment: The permissions (AWS IAM policies) assigned to the function's IAM role, are things that allow the Lambda function to access other AWS resources, via the AWS API. Those are totally irrelevant to sending some HTTP request to an external URL.

Comment: @MarkB I was fairly certain of that but the CloudWatch log so so vague I threw in everything.

Comment: That website could be blocking bots, or just blocking AWS IP addresses. As someone who owns a website that gets absolutely pummeled by bots, I suggest you email the site owner asking if it is OK and to pull data from their site using an automated script running on AWS.

Comment: It'd be a lot nicer to dan.me.uk if the file was cached locally and not downloaded every time that function is called.